# Paste Highlighted Cells to Other Column

Tags: excel, vba, conditional-formatting

I have a conditional format that highlights all duplicate values on column A and would like all highlighted values to be pasted on column B. The issue is, there are 160k rows for the column, and am unable to find what cells are highlighted due to the sheer number of rows. Is it possible to copy all highlighted cells in column A and paste those values onto column B? I attempted to sort by filter color, but the limit is 10,000 rows so if row 10,001 is highlighted, it will not be displayed.

```
A                B
abc1           abc1
abc2           abc1
abc1              
test3                
abc3
```

I am using this highlight color, not sure what value it is in VBA. [image]

Comment: *Is it possible to copy all highlighted cells in column A and paste those values onto column B?* - Yes, it is.

Answer (score 2):

You can use a `For`..`Next` with an `If` statement to find the cells that are highlighted. Here, `i` iterates through cells and if the cell is highlighted, it's pasted into the next column with `rng.offset(n,1)`. `n = n + 1` pastes the highlighted value to the next empty row in column B, rather than pasting the value into the same cell repeatedly. Also, `application.screenupdating = False` makes it more efficient. 
Try This:

```
Sub copyhighlight()

    Dim rng As Range
    Set rng = Range("A1", Range("A1").End(xlUp))
    Dim lastrow As Long
    lastrow = Range("A1").CurrentRegion.Rows.Count

    Dim i As Long
    Dim n As Long

    Application.ScreenUpdating = False

    n = 0

    For i = 1 To lastrow
        If rng.Cells(i, 1).Interior.Color = vbYellow Then
            rng(i, 1).Copy
            rng.Offset(n, 1).PasteSpecial xlPasteAll
            n = n + 1
        End If
    Next i

    Application.ScreenUpdating = True

End Sub
```

Comment: Hmmmm... I ran it, but it's not pasting to column B. Any thoughts?

Comment: `rng.Offset(i, 1).PasteSpecial xlPasteAll` should paste it to column B, but it won't start at the top of the column. Rather, it will paste the value in column B, in the same row, `i`,  in which the colored cell was found.

Comment: Is it possible to paste on the top of the column B? When I filter column B, there are no values and this could be due to the number of records, 160k.

Comment: Hmmmm... it works on my smaller dataset < 10, but for my 160k dataset it doesn't work. Wonder what it could be.

Comment: So, I highlighted a cell further down on my 160k dataset and the formula works great! I think it's just the sheer number of records on the file that is causing the issue.

Comment: @MSauce try it now. I added `application.screenupdating = false`. I tested on 160k rows of data, it took about 10 seconds, but it gave me the expected result.

Comment: So, I think I found the issue. Conditionally formatted cells, aren't treated the same as cells that are highlighted. I tested this by highlighting a cell at row 140k, and your code pasted as intended. I updated the If statement to ....(i, 1).DisplayFormat.Interior.Color = vbYellow.... but it freezes on me :(.